# New to assembly, a bit confused regarding some instructions

Tags: assembly, windbg

So I'm practicing/slowly but surely learning and brushing up on my Assembly. Here's a random disassembled kernel function as an example:

```
81a1e85f 8b450c          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] // Moving value stored at memory address contained in the ebp register+0Ch to the eax register.
81a1e862 8b4048          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+48h] // Moving value stored at memory address contained in the eax register+48h to the eax register.
81a1e865 8945f0          mov     dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax // Moving value stored at memory address contained in the epb-10h register to the eax register?
81a1e868 6a00            push    0 // ?
81a1e86a 8bc7            mov     eax,edi // Move contents of the edi register into eax.
81a1e86c c745fc22010000  mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],122h // ?
81a1e873 e8bf010000      call    nt!PspGetPreviousProcessThread (81a1ea37) // Call the function name nt!PspGetPreviousProcessThread?
81a1e878 8b5d14          mov     ebx,dword ptr [ebp+14h] // Moving value stored at memory address contained in the ebp register+14h to the ebx register.
```

I'm pretty new to most of it, so there's no doubt I'm either wrong on some of it, or wrong on all of it. Can anyone let me know what's going on most of all where I commented '?' as I am unfamiliar.

Also, anything in brackets -- [ebp-4] for example, this is considered a dereferenced pointer, correct?

Comment: Yes, anything in brackets, like `[ebp - 4]` is a dereferenced pointer. "Whatever is in the `EBP` register, minus 4, used as an address". More precisely, on a 32bit system, it is the first local variable of the current subroutine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Moving value stored at memory address contained in the ebp register+0Ch to the eax register.
// correct
    mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] 

// Moving value stored at memory address contained in the eax register+48h to the eax register.
// correct
    mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+48h] 

// Moving value stored at memory address contained in the epb-10h register to the eax register?    
// no, moving content of eax register (dword) to location [ebp-10h]
mov     dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 

// ?
// pushes a 32-bit zero on stack - probably an argument to the call below
    push    0 

// Move contents of the edi register into eax.
// correct
    mov     eax,edi 

// ?
// store the 32-bit value 122h to location [ebp-4]
    mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],122h 

// Call the function name nt!PspGetPreviousProcessThread?
// correct
    call    nt!PspGetPreviousProcessThread (81a1ea37) 

// Moving value stored at memory address contained in the ebp register+14h to the ebx register
// correct
    mov     ebx,dword ptr [ebp+14h]
```

Comment: Will mark as answer when I can.

A question regarding MOV instructions.... oops, hit hinter - let me edit.

So is the register that's behind the other register the one that's always going to be moved to?

Example:

1 - mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] 

ebp is moving to eax.

2 - mov     dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax

eax is moving to ebp.

Comment: Yes, in Intel syntax, target is on the left, source is on the right. (not all instructions modify target, think `cmp`, `test`, and so on).

Answer (score 5):

> Also, anything in brackets -- [ebp-4] for example, this is considered
>   a dereferenced pointer, correct?

While this is true in the examples you have provided, note that it is not true in all cases in the x86/x64 syntax. Specifically, the Load Effective Address (LEA) command uses square brackets but does not perform a pointer dereference. For example:

```
LEA EAX, [EBP+4]
```

Would add 4 to the value of EBP and store the result of the addition in EAX.

There's an excellent article by Matt Pietrek from 1998 (!) that covers a lot of these basics:

http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/hood0298.aspx

Comment: Was napping, sorry for the late +1. Much appreciated, thank you for the clarification!